# cornmeal crust on chicken is too gritty, is there a way to fix after chx has been baked?

Tags: chicken, batter, breading, cornmeal

I made oven baked chicken using coarse ground cornmeal (obviously a mistake). Dredged chx in flour, then egg, then cornmeal.  I'm worried I'll break a tooth on the gritty corn particles in the breading! I don't want to throw it out. Is there a way to soften the breading even though the chicken is cooked?  Next time I'll use crushed cornflakes or something else.

Answer (score 3):

The only way you are going to soften the corn meal in the breading is to let it get a bit soggy. Store it in a plastic container in the fridge overnight and let it's own moisture do the job. If the result you get is good then great, if the skin isn't good after that then just peel it off and eat the chicken.

Comment: +1 for "peel and eat the chicken". Making it soggy is a long shot, but saving the chicken is a surprisingly good and easy idea.